# Spring boot properties parsed incorrectly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have the below yaml property file in my spring-boot project. Refer the file code below :

```
db:
  useEmbedded: false
  type: postgres
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
  username: akhil
  password: akhil
  port: 5432
```

I am loading these properties using code :

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;

import java.util.List;

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppProperties {

    public static class DB {
        public final boolean useEmbedded;
        public final String type;
        public final String url;
        public final String name;
        public final String username;
        public final String password;
        public final int port;

        public DB(boolean useEmbedded, String type, String url, String name, String username, String password, int port) {
            this.useEmbedded = useEmbedded;
            this.type = type;
            this.url = url;
            this.name = name;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.port = port;
        }
    }

    public final DB db;

    public AppProperties(DB db {
        this.db = db;
    }
}
```

Out of all the property file configurations, encoded values are loaded for **url**, **username**, **password**.

I am getting the encrypted value instead of getting it as plain text, refer below :

```
url : xqs9UXmQlYvyC50qx1GqcnYtIRM5/RewTgdPLmedu8qmaARZNfOMMwYswjk5AMIlS1bGWHC1GaTdlbhlMfRobHfUKwXLTKMUJH5zu87G1pQ8Et4KXLxFQ6xaPIcDtDhB
username : GxVMYrjHGKc4Nee1ftfoig==
password : M2LTxSQtjJKOZLJPwB1sZg==
```

It is the case in the Ubuntu-20.04 but this is working fine in Mac-OS where i get the actual plain text value. The IDE which i am using is Intellij-community-edition.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because of the encoding used in your ubuntu setup. Please try encoding the text from your properties from your yaml file using ascii (Change in your IDE or use any online tool). If you are using intellij, you can find encoding option at bottom right, or from the settings, refer: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

You can use this tool to convert your text, and updated your yaml: https://native2ascii.net/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @balias but If that could be the case then why do only 3 properties have different encoding and others have different encoding. Please suggest.